# Rspec: how can I access what the scenario is tagged with within the scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have an rspec scenario that looks like:

```
    scenario "some description of the scenario", :js => true, :slow => true, :wip => true do
      sleep 60
      ...
```

But I would like to call `sleep` conditionally based on what the scenario is tagged with, something like:

```
    scenario "some description of the scenario", :js => true, :slow => true, :wip => true do
      sleep 60 if tags[:slow] && !tags[:wip]
      ...
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since rspec doesn't have a `scenario` method, I'm guessing that you're using [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) or [steak](https://github.com/cavalle/steak) and that it's really just an alias for `it`. In that case, rspec internally refers to this block of code as an "example," and you can access the meta data like this:

```
sleep 60 if example.metadata[:slow]  # sleep if example is tagged with :slow => true
```

You can also put the metadata on the example group, the `describe` block that encloses the various examples. See this: http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/dir/metadata/user-defined-metadata